# GPRS/GSM SIM900 Shield not working with Arduino

Tags: gsm

I have a few questions related to GPRS/GSM SIM900 Shield not working with Arduino.

To keep it short I have a list of concrete questions:

1. Is the Arduino GSM library compatible with the [Geeetech GPRS/GSM SIM900 Shield](http://eud.dx.com/product/geeetech-gprs-gsm-sim900-shield-board-for-arduino-green-844377853#.VxXuxTCF6hd)?
2. On the board the green LED blinks every 3 seconds which I have read
   means that it is connected. However, when I try to use any of the
   GSM examples, in regard to internet, I either get error messages or
   simply no progress in the program. For instance, in the `testGPRS`
   sketch it sits stuck at the port where it says "Connecting GSM
   network...". And in the `bandManagement` example sketch it can't find
   the current band,as well as the modem not responding, well basically nothing works, except that the
   shield itself indicates it is connected to a network.

The SIM card I'm using is data exclusively and can't be used for voice calls or SMS. It has no pin code and works as my secondary SIM card (it shares the same subscription as my primary card).

Edit:
I have now tested the SMS capabillities of the board with another simcard, that works with no problems, seems only the internet won't work.

Comment: which arduino board are you are using? How are you are powering this board?

Comment: Im using arduino UNO, i power it through USB on my laptop.

Comment: I have also acquired a 9 Volt battery to test if extra power will help when I have tried it I will respond with the result.

Comment: These modules consume a lot of current (2A at least) when using GPRS. A 9V battery is no good as it cant supply this current. Look for an 18650 battery or 3.7 V LiPo cell that can supply 2A easily or a wall adapter coupled with a buck converter. Voltage should be at least 4 V but no more than 4.7V.

Comment: Ok so i tried the 18650 batteries and it is still not working.